# User authentication vs digitally signing requests

Tags: authentication, digital-signature

I'm working on a class project where I need to add a layer of security to my REST server. My server is a Facebook like server where users can post stuff etc. How should I add authentication to my server?

- Do user authentication per session, or
- Digitally sign all requests from a particular user